# Python convert string to hex then convert to bytes

Tags: python, string, hex, byte, encode

I have this string :

```
cmd_str = '02003311c3002404005803 '
```

When I convert this to bytes I get  this. (using windows 10 Python 3)

```
b'\x02\x003\x11\xc3\x00$\x04\x00X\x03'
```

I expected to get this:

```
b'\x02\0x0\0x33\33\0x11\0xc3\0x0\0x24\0x4\0x0\0x58\0x3'
```

Why?

```
cmd_str = '02'+'00'+'33'+'11'+'c3'+'00'+'24'+'04'+'00'+'58'+'03'

n = 2

out = [(cmd_str[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(cmd_str), n)]

hexlist=[]   
for i in out:
    an_integer = int(i,16)  #read string in convert to integer.
        
    hex_v=hex(an_integer)
    print(hex_v)
    hexlist.append(hex_v)
result = bytes([int(x,0) for x in hexlist])
```

Comment: How are you converting the string?

Comment: cmd_str = '02'+'00'+'33'+'11'+'c3'+'00'+'24'+'04'+'00'+'58'+'03'

n = 2

out = [(cmd_str[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(cmd_str), n)]

hexlist=[]   
for i in out:
    an_integer = int(i,16)  #read string in convert to integer.
        
    hex_v=hex(an_integer)
    print(hex_v)
    hexlist.append(hex_v)
result = bytes([int(x,0) for x in hexlist])

Comment: First off, the escape sequences will only ever be `\x` followed by two hex digits - not `\0x` followed by anything. Second, it only shows you escape sequences for bytes that don't correspond to printable ASCII characters. This does not mean there's anything wrong with the `bytes` data, it just means that Python doesn't *represent* it the way you expected.

Comment: Anything that is displayable as a character will be displayed as a character rather than a hex escape.  That's just the way Python works.

Comment: (For what it's worth, I wish it *did* work more in line with your expectation. It's better that we stop pretending that undecoded bytes are "text" or "characters" in any meaningful way.)

Comment: As an aside, you just want to use `import binascii; result = binascii.unhexlify(cmd_str)`...

Comment: My  embedded controller only understand the expected byte string format. How do I convert the converted string to "look" like the expected string?

Comment: What you show for your "expected string" isn't valid syntax.  But to understand what's happening try `b'\x02\x003\x11\xc3\x00$\x04\x00X\x03'==b'\x02\x00\x33\x11\xc3\x00\x24\x04\x00\x58\x03'`.